# Проблема с выводом шутки на discord py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, discord-api

Проблема в том, что этот сайт очень странно генерирует шутку для питона, а конкретно, она содержится там в нескольких строках и получается что-то по типу этого:
[image: как она содержится на сайте]
[image: как она получается в питоне]
Сплит, лист пробовал. Он изначально под ключем 'content' содержит "неправильную строку" и не может с ней ничего сделать
Добавить в текстовый файл и потом построчно считать тоже никак, такая же проблема (под ключем неправильная строка)

Как извлечь шутку из словаря в одну строку или списком строк или вообще любым способом. Главное чтобы извлеклась и можно было ее в нормальном виде вывести в чат.

Вот код, заранее спасибо

```
import discord
import requests
import json

bot = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if '-анекдот' in str(message.content).lower():
        channel = bot.get_channel(ID)
        url = 'http://rzhunemogu.ru/RandJSON.aspx?CType=1'
        jou = requests.get(url)
        json_data = json.loads(jou.text)
        joke = json_data['joke']
        await channel.send(joke)
```

Comment: joke = json_data['joke']['content']

Answer (score 0):

`json` можно брать прямо из ответа, отдельно модуль `json` не нужен, а чтобы решить вашу проблему с переводами строки в `json`, нужно указать параметр `strict=False`. Привожу только код получения шутки, без кода для бота:

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'http://rzhunemogu.ru/RandJSON.aspx?CType=1'
responce = requests.get(url)
json_data = responce.json(strict=False)
joke = json_data['content']
print(joke)
```